# Why does VS not generate a .lib file if there is no .cpp file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, static-libraries

I am trying to create a simple 2D library, consisting entirely of class templates. I created an empty project, changed configuration type to static library, and then added my header files. It currently looks like this:

[image]

When I try to build this project, the build succeeds but no `.lib` file is actually created.

[image: Build succeeds, but no .lib file generated]

When googling for a way to fix this, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950509/build-succeeded-but-no-lib-file-gets-created) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32674754/13699024), which refers to the same problem of not being able to generate a `.lib` file because the project contains no `.cpp` file.

The answer says that they solved it by adding a `.cpp` file that just includes all the header files:
[image]

And this does indeed solve the issue:
[image]

But surely there's a more elegant way of solving this? Why doesn't VS want to generate a `.lib` file if you don't do this?

Comment: What's the purpose of building a lib file if your library is only made out of templates? The user only needs to include your header files anyway, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @UnholySheep Not sure I understand what you mean. Do libraries never consist of just class templates or just classes?

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) - TL;DR; Your `lib` file would be empty if you don't put explicit instantiations of your class templates and function templates in it. That's usually _not_ what you want. "_Do libraries never consist of just class templates_" - Yes, and they are then usually called "header only" libraries.

Comment: Libraries consist of _compiled code_.  Templates are instructions for _writing code_.  The common redistributable for templates is "a header file"

Comment: Wikipedia page on [Header-Only libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only)